# Child component not detecting changes

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a weird problem in react, I have a simple child/parent component like:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default function TestComponent(dataOnParent, id) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(id, dataOnParent);
    }, [dataOnParent]);

    return (<></>);
}

export default function ParentComponent() {
    const [testComponent, settestComponent] = React.useState(undefined);
    const [dataOnParent, setdataOnParent] = React.useState(1);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        settestComponent(<TestComponent
            dataOnParent={dataOnParent}
            id={1} 
        />);
    }, []);
    
    React.useEffect(() => {
        setdataOnParent(dataOnParent+1);
    }, [pageButtonClick]); //triggered by page button click
    
    return (
        <>
          {testComponent} /* This does not trigger */
          <TestComponent dataOnParent={dataOnParent} id={2} /> /* This triggers */
        </>
  );
}}
```

pageButtonClick is triggerd by a page button. If I create a child component, using `<TestComponent markersOnParent={markersOnParent} id={2} />` , then the
child component useEffect can successfully be triggered when dataOnParent changes.
But if I use `{testComponent}`, it won't be trigged.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The `dataOnParent` passed into your stored `testComponent` is the value at the point it was stored, and you never update `testComponent`, so it never receives a new value for that property.

Comment: This is (one reason) why storing component instances in state is a bad idea. Only store data in state; then use that data to determine what components, and props, to render

Comment: @BrianThompson 
Could I ask you one more question? 
Should I always avoid storing component instance in a state?
const [overlayById, setOverlayById] = useState<Map<string, ReactNode>>(new Map());
    <OverlayContext.Provider value={context}>
      {children}
      {[...overlayById.entries()].map(([id, element]) => (
        <React.Fragment key={id}>{element}</React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </OverlayContext.Provider>

because I saw these line of codes which handles rendering of multiple overlaying components. Do you think it's not preferable?

Answer (score -1):

Simply you have to destructure the data coming from the parent component

```
export default function TestComponent({dataOnParent, id}) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(id, dataOnParent);
    }, [dataOnParent]);

    return (<></>);
}
```

Also, react knows if this is a component or not by seeing if the first letter is CapitalCase and the correct way to render `JSX components` is to use this way `<Component />`